# v4l2, video capture via usb cam HELP

Tags: command-line, camera, video4linux

So im trying to capture video with my usb camera via vlc using this C code-> [video capture example](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html).
After compile & run to the terminal i have a file that is supposed to be my video data and should be used by VLC (obviously it is not in a video format) but i don't know how to do it. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy thing to check if your system knows your webcam are command `lsusb`, `ls -l /dev/video*` and `hwinfo --usb`.
You should be in the user-group video for most applications.
You should try to start VLC by command to open your webcam to see that VLC can use it direct from start: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam#VLC

In your C code example at the beginning of main there is the webcam device file "/dev/video0". You can test this by the VLC-commands above.

Some more info: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Set_up_a_Webcam_with_Linux

There is the `file` command: `man 1 file`. What does this tells you about the output file? Maybe this output from your libv4l-example is really garbage. I dont understand your question what does your libv4l-C-code-example has to do with vlc. It seems to me your example is grabbing RAW video data to the output. This can be tested by vlc command: See ***https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882375/playing-yuv-on-vlc-player***

Comment: well, after the "file" command i see it is an ELF file (more specifically ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=bfaac272d1a98c4927a946d0cb7b66ecf5bbc493, not stripped)
What i want to ask is how to use this ELF file (apart from the "readelf" command) in order to display properly my video data which is in the ELF file.